# Accessing pushState URL on page load

Tags: javascript, html, url, pushstate

I'm trying to create a gallery that allow custom url rather than url prefix with hashtag.

For example:

> http://www.myportfolio.com/gallery/3

rather than

> http://www.myportfolio.com/gallery#3

---

so far everything is working fine, if I access from http://www.myportfolio.com/gallery I was able to go to the next and previous image with the url updated.

My main issue now is although the url is now dynamic but it still cannot be bookmarked, if I enter http://www.myportfolio.com/gallery/4 to go the 4th image it doesn't work.

Is there a Javascript approach to this or do you need a combination of PHP to redirect the url?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use client side JavaScript to handle this, although you'll need to set up the server so that every URL (that isn't for something like an image or script) loads the bootstrap document your SPA runs on. You just need to check `location.href` when the page loads and then set up the content you want.

That said, doing so is a **very bad idea** that completely misses the point of using pushState and friends in the first place.

The two points of being able to have a normal URL are that:

- Clients where the JavaScript fails still get a useful page
- The content for that URL is loaded in the initial page load (so it is available faster)

If you aren't going to take advantage of that, you might as well go back to hashbangs.